# Calling a synchronized method from another synchronized method, both on different object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Lets say we have two classes A, B and synchronized methods methodA, methodB of the respective classes. If we call synchronized methodB from synchronized methodA whether the thread still hold lock on ObjectA while methodB is still executing?

```
Class A
{
   public synchronized void methodA()
   {
       //do something;
       synchronized(ObjectB)
       {
          ObjectB.methodB();
       }
   }
}

Class B
{
   public synchronized void methodB()
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: You should fix the question, but no the thread doesn't release other locks when it acquires new locks. It only release locks when exiting the synchronized parts or when waiting.

Comment: Can you show a more complete working example?  It appears as if you have 3 sychnronizations going on, some instance of A, some instance called ObjOfClassB, and another instance called ObjectB.

Comment: @fedup My bad. ObjOfClassB and ObjectB are same. I've corrected the code.

Comment: The inner synchronization in `methodA()` is redundant. However when you have this sort of thing you must ensure that everybody acquires the locks in the same order, otherwise deadlock will result. For example if `methodB()` called a synchronized method of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The lock will held as long as you are in sync block. It is allowed to lock as many locks as you need but this nested synchronization can impact the overall performance of your application.